# Python 3 code is not performing as expected, Giving incorrect numbers

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I've recently gotten into Python, and I couldn't come up with any things to make. So i decided i'd port all of my Project Euler stuff over to Python just to have something to do. But basically, the code below is supposed to find the product of a, b, and c, where a + b + c = 1000. (Pythagorean triplet)

```
from math import sqrt

def solve():
    product = 0
    for a in range(1, 500):
        for b in range(1, 500):
            needed = sqrt(a*a + b*b)
            if a + b + needed == 1000:
                    product = a * b * needed
                    return product
    return product

print(solve())
```

This code produces the correct result, which is 31875000.0. I want it to return an integer, and not a floating point value. I tried doing

```
needed = round(sqrt(a*a + b*b))
```

but for some reason, this returns the number 498002, which is not even close to being the same number. I've also tried using Floor from the math library, but that also does the same thing, as well as int().  Is there something that I'm overlooking? Or is this a bug? Or what. I'm using Python 3.5 if that matters.

Comment: What's wrong with `int(solve())`?

Comment: @I'L'I I didn't think about it that way when I was writing it, although now that its been pointed out it seems extremely obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you `round()` off, or even do `int()` to convert the `sqrt()` result to integer, you are losing precision, like in case of `i` being 2 and `j` being `499` , since `i` is so small , the sqrt of `a^2 + b^2` would be something like - `499.0040079999358` - rounding that off would give `499` . And your program would wrongly assume this to be a triplet ,since `499 + 499 + 2` is `1000`.

Instead of rounding the result of `sqrt` you should convert the product to `integer` before returning. Example -

```
from math import sqrt

def solve():
    product = 0
    for a in range(1, 500):
        for b in range(1, 500):
            needed = sqrt(a*a + b*b)
            if a + b + needed == 1000:
                    product = a * b * needed
                    return int(product)
    return product

print(solve())
```

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense. Now that you point that out i feel really stupid for not realizing that to begin with. Thanks a lot.